# Which engines are Jet-A used in?

Tags: fuel, jet-engine

Is Jet-A used in turbojets or is it just used in turbofans, turboprops, and the SMA SR305-230 for Cessna?

Comment: Why do you think there should be difference between turbojet and turbofan? They are almost the same.

Comment: I thought the military might use something different because power is better than efficiency in that line of work.

Comment: Most military aircraft have turbofans as well. Including fighters. True turbojets are extremely rare these days. Plus for military having just one stock to supply is much bigger asset than any gain in performance specially tuned fuel could bring.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jet-A is mostly for turbine engines in general. Turbine engines can be fueled with nearly anything that you can spray over an open flame and will burn.

It is not a substitute for avgas, for the same reasons that diesel is not a substitute for petrol. You can fuel a diesel engine with Jet-A under some circumstances.

Comment: Normal diesel engine won't run very well with Jet-A1, but it is possible to build one for use with Jet-A1 (or any other specific jet fuel type, but Jet-A1 is most common in Europe) and such engines are used on some new aircraft especially since avgas is heavily taxed in Europe.

Comment: "Turbine engines can be fueled with nearly anything that you can spray over an open flame and will burn."  With one partial exception - they generally don't take well to fuels with solid combustion products (since these deposit on the turbine blades and do bad things to the engine), unless the engine burns hot enough to keep the exhaust temperature above their vaporisation point until well past the outlet.

Answer (score 1):

Jet-A/A1 is used by pretty much all civilian turbine aircraft. The US military use JP-8 which is similar but with extra additives in pretty much all their aircraft.

The fuels can also be used in suitably designed diesel engines. AIUI the US military runs pretty much all it's vehicles off JP-8 and some airports use Jet-A/A1 for their ground vehicles. In both cases the motivation is simplified fuel handling.

Due to cost/availability/environmental concerns with avgas there has been a push to develop aviation diesel engines that run on jet A/A1 (and in some cases can also run on automotive Diesel). However the GA market is relatively small, certification costs are high and making a Diesel engine light and reliable enough for aircraft use is not easy. So-far only a small proportion of piston aircraft have Diesel engine options available.